# Finding difference between two tree structures C#

Tags: c#, linq, tree

I am in need of a function that will compare the difference between two different file structures and return that difference as a file structure.

I have a class, "Element" that has properties ID and Children, with ID being a string and Children being a collection of Element.

```
public class Element
{
  string ID { get; }
  IEnumerable<Element> Children { get; }
}
```

Now, let's say I have the following structures of Elements:

```
Structure A                Structure B
  - Category 1              - Category 1
      - Child X                - Child X
      - Child Y                - Child Z
  - Category 2
```

I would like to return a structure that tells me which elements are present in structure A but missing from structure B, which would look as follows:

```
Structure Diff
  - Category 1
       - Child Y
  - Category 2
```

Is there a simple way of doing this using LINQ, or a straight-forward algorithm (Assuming there can be many levels to the tree).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can just compare two enumerables of strings that contains paths of files:

```
Category 1\
Category 1\Child X
Category 1\Child Y
Category 2\

Category 1\
Category 1\Child X
Category 1\Child Z
```

Having these two enumerables you can call [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx) method to keep items from the first enumerable that are missing in the second enumerable.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't really think to implement it this way!

Answer (score 1):

Sample implementation to get you started (tested only on one case):

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var c1 = new Element[] {
            new Element() {ID = "Category 1", Children = new Element[] {
                new Element() {ID = "Child X" },
                new Element() {ID = "Child Y" }
            }},
            new Element() {ID = "Category 2",}
        };
        var c2 = new Element[] {
            new Element() {ID = "Category 1", Children = new Element[] {
                new Element() {ID = "Child X" },
                new Element() {ID = "Child Z" }
            }},                
        };

        var keys = new HashSet<string>(GetFlatKeys(c2));
        var result = FindDiff(c1, keys).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(result);            
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Element> FindDiff(Element[] source, HashSet<string> keys, string key = null) {
        if (source == null)
            yield break;
        foreach (var parent in source) {
            key += "|" + parent.ID;
            parent.Children = FindDiff(parent.Children, keys, key).ToArray();
            if (!keys.Contains(key) || (parent.Children != null && parent.Children.Length > 0)) {                   
                yield return parent;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetFlatKeys(IEnumerable<Element> source, string key = null) {
        if (source == null)
            yield break;
        foreach (var parent in source) {
            key += "|" + parent.ID;
            yield return key;
            foreach (var c in GetFlatKeys(parent.Children, key))
                yield return c;
        }
    }
}
```

As said in another answer, it's easier to first get flat list of keys for each element in second tree, then filter out elements from the first tree based on that list.

Comment: You're right, but I'm pretty sure that your solution doesn't work (I think GetFlatKeys() is wrong). 

(Just pointing that out for anyone else who stumbles on this thread).